# Retrieving image for order item with Shoppe gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Having trouble retrieving an order items image for display in current order.

Trying to do something like this -

```
<% order.order_items.each do |item| %>
  <td><%= image_tag item.default_image.path, :width => '200px', :style => "float:right" %></td>
<% end %>
```

Has anyone done this before/have any ideas? I'm currently getting an undefined method for 'default_image'.

Thanks!!!!!!!

**edit**

```
    undefined method `default_image' for #<Shoppe::OrderItem:0x007f494834a308>



    app/views/shared/_current_basket.html.erb:14:in `block in 
_app_views_shared__current_basket_html_erb__3066740198477643044_69976360480880'
    app/views/shared/_current_basket.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_shared__current_basket_html_erb__3066740198477643044_69976360480880'
    app/views/orders/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_orders_show_html_erb___1356602738108519273_49665800'
```

default_image is defined for Shoppe::Product, so I suppose I'm just looking for a similar method to retrieve images for products that are in an order. I cant seem to find anything in the gem or docs, wondering if anyone knows a work around or something that I missed!

Comment: show the full error please

Comment: where you have defined the method `default_image` ?

Comment: I havent defined it myself, I'm using the Shoppe gem. default_image is the method used to call images on Shoppe::Product, was wondering what can be used to get the image for products that belong to an order. I'll clarify this in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

<%= image_tag item.ordered_item.default_image.path, :width => "###px", :style => "style:style" %>